# Swift: CoreLocation how to know what user allowed

Tags: swift, location

In my application, I ask the user the location permission with the option always allow. Since iOS 13 the option always allow is removed from the popup. So I have to create a flow and check if the `always` option is already enabled.

I thought that `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` returns what option the user has chosen, but no.

If I click on the `While using the App` option, it will return `.authorizedAlways`, if I go to the application's parameter location I see that it is the `while using the App` option that is enabled. I need to know if the `always` option is enabled

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have requested "Always" authorization using  `CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` on iOS 13, and user has chosen "Allow While in Use" in the first popup, then your app enters so called "Provisional Always Authorization" mode/state. During this period permissions that your app sees and that your user sees are different. Location events are not delivered in the background.

Provisional Always authorization is described in detail in [Apple's WWDC 2019 "What's New in Core Location"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/).

**Quick summary**

1. Your app requests "Always" authorization using `CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`
2. User is presented with this popup:

[image: First permissions popup]

3. User chooses "Allow While in Use". Your app's LocationManager's delegate method `locationManager(_,didChangeAuthorization:)` will be called with `.authorizedAlways`.
4. User sees "While in Use" in Settings.app, but your app can use any method that requires "Always" permissions.

[image: Provisional Always Authorization perspectives]

5. Your app used methods that require "Always" permissions, like tracking location in the background, monitoring geofence events, etc. Once those events are generated, system holds on to them and doesn't deliver them to your app.
6. When the user is not busy (dwells on the phone's home screen for some time), they are presented with another popup, where they can truly grant "Always" authorization, promoting from "Provisional Always" or demoting the app to "While Using" authorization:

[image: Second permissions popup]

7. If the user chose "Change to Always Allow", only then the events will be delivered to the app. LocationManager's delegate method `locationManager(_,didChangeAuthorization:)` will be called with `.authorizedAlways` again, or will be called with `.authorizedWhenInUse` if the user has chosen "Keep Only While Using" instead.

[image: Provisional Always Authorization agreement]

**Possible solutions**

This mode was designed to be backwards compatible with apps written using previous iOS SDK versions. Those apps will see what they expect to see, they'll just receive no events using "Provisional Always" authorization.

But this presents a challenge, because there is no API to distinguish between the true "Always" authorization and "Provisional Always". Some heuristics that can help:

1. When you first request "Always" authorization on iOS 13 and receive "Always" in return, this is definitely a "Provisional Always" authorization.
2. Second `locationManager(_,didChangeAuthorization:)` call with `.authorizedAlways` status can be an indicator that user has promoted the app to "Always". But this is not reliable, as this method can be called multiple times with the same permission status. For example, every time you start your LocationManager.
3. When you finally receive your events. For example, there will be no location events in the background during "Provisional Always" authorization, but if you start receiving them, it means you truly have "Always" permissions. This is what I would look for.